# make server backup, and keep owner with rsync

Tags: server, backup, rsync

I recently configured a little server for test some services, now, before an upgrade or install new software, I want to make an exact copy of my files, with owners, groups and permissions, also the symlinks.

I tried with rsync  to keep the owner and group but in the machine who receives the copy I lost them.

```
rsync -azp -H /directorySource/ myUser@192.168.0.30:/home/myUser/myBackupDirectory
```

My intention is to do it with the / folder, to keep all my configurations just in case, I have 3 services who have it's own users and maybe makes  modifications in folders outside it's home.

In the destination folder appear with my destination user, whether I do the copy from the server as if I do it from the destination, it doesn't keep the users and groups!, I create the same user, tried with sudo, even a friend tried with 777 folder :)

cp theoretically serves the same but doesn't work over ssh, anyway I tried to do it in the server but have many errors. As I remembered the command tar also keep the permissions and owners but have errors because the server it's working and it isn't so fast the process to restore. I remember too the magic dd command, but I made a big partition. Rsync looked the best option to do it, and to keep synchronized the backup. I saw rsync in the new version work well with owners but I have the package upgraded.

Anybody have some idea how I do this, or how is the normal process to keep my own server well backuped, to restore just making the partition again?

The services are taiga, a project manager platform, a git repository, a code reviewer, and so on, all are working well with nginx over Ubuntu Server. I haven't looked other backup methods because I thought rsync with a cron job do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Your command would be fine, but you need to run as **root** user on the remote end (only root has permission to set file owners):

```
rsync -az -H /directorySource/ root@192.168.0.30:/home/myUser/myBackupDirectory
```

You also need to ensure that you use rsync's `-o` option to preserve owners, and `-g` to preserve groups, but as these are implied by `-a` your command is OK. I removed `-p` because that's also implied by `-a`.

You'll also need root access, on the local end, to do the reverse transfer (if you want to restore your files).

---

If that doesn't work for you (no root access), then you might consider doing this using `tar`. A proper archive is probably the correct tool for the job, and will contain all the correct user data. Again, root access will be needed to write that back to the file-system.